# C++ Deleting memory from pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I got a question about this code:

```
void main() 
{
int *num = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10); /XXX
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    num[i] = i;

int *num2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    num2[i] = i + 10;

num = num2;
}
```

Is the memory in the XXX line deleted when I equal the first pointer to the second?

Comment: Side note: `void main()` is invalid, it should be `int main()`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use C++, you should be using `new int[10]` [1]... And the answer to your question is "no, it is not deleted, you have a memory leak".

You need to use:

```
free(num); 
num = num2;
```

And you should of course also free the "new" value of `num` at some point.

[1] Or better yet, use `vector<int> num(10);` - completely avoiding dynamic memory allocation in your code. E.g. the following code will take care of allocated memory:

```
vector<int> num(10);
vector<int> num2(10);
// ... Do something with num & num2 values.
num2 = num;
```

This would even work if `num2` held a different number of values; its size is adjusted to match `num`. A lot harder to get that right with manual `malloc` calls.

Comment: You can't suggest `new` without a mention of an RAII alternative :p

Comment: I shouldn't but I have to say "manual memory management" would be a better term than "dynamic memory allocation", since the latter obviously still happens, and it would matter if you were, say, looking to use as little dynamic memory allocation anywhere as possible.